# Simplifying Formulae

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing an 8th grade math text book and I came across this simple problem:

$$T = 2\pi  \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}} \text{ then }T\text{ is _________  proportional to }\sqrt l$$

I had actually solved this, but now I forgot how I solved this.
I came till $\frac{T \sqrt g}{2\pi} = \sqrt l$, but I could not conclude.

please help

Comment: I think there are only a very few choices for what goes in the blank; basically, it's a choice between two words. Do you know the words? and how to distinguish between them?

Comment: In the original equation, $T=2\pi\sqrt{1/g}$, the variable $l$ does not even appear. Are you missing some details?

Comment: I believe the typo occurred in the original equation.  It should be $$\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}} $$

Comment: The equation is T = 2π√('L'/g)

Comment: The reason I say that, is because the equation is for the period of a pendulum of length $l$

Comment: Yes. (monroej).

Comment: Yes .I came across this formula for the time period of a pendulum when I was in 7th

Comment: So the two phrases that @GerryMyerson is hinting at are "directly proportional" and "Inversely proportional".

Comment: If $T=2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$, then you have $T=\left(2\pi\sqrt{\frac{1}{g}}\right)\cdot \sqrt{l}$ which means $T$ is linearly proportional to $\sqrt{l}$. Is this what you need?

Comment: I wanted to know if T was either directly or inversely proportional to √'L'

Comment: Good. So: what does "directly proportional" mean to you? and what does "inversely proportional" mean to you?

Comment: Suppose, if T was dp to √'L', we would represent it as T = k × √'L'; where k is a constant.

Comment: It is not 1/g its 'l'/g (l for lucky)

Comment: Here your 'k' is $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{g}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$T=2π\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\quad \text{is the given equation.}$$
$$\text{Since }\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$$
$$\text{We can write }\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}} \text{ as } \frac{\sqrt{l}}{\sqrt{g}}$$
$$\text{therefore we can write  } T=2π\frac{\sqrt{l}}{\sqrt{g}}$$
$$\text{Multiplying by } \sqrt{g} \text{ and dividing by 2π, we get your answer of } \frac{T\sqrt{g}}{2π}=\sqrt{l}$$